# Avoid having to pass arguments to update

Tags: django, django-models

Is it possible in django to replace:

```
MyModel.objects.get_stuff_to_close_query_set(time).update(
    status="closed", 
    open_time=None,
    opener=None
)
```

with:

```
MyModel.objects.my_custom_query_set(time).close()
```

where close() is doing the same thing as update in the first statement? If so, how do I implement close()?

Additionally, is it possible to hide the query set by doing something like:

```
MyModel.objects.close_stuff(time)
```

Comment: Can you share the `MyModel` and its manager?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem Update question as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this by subclassing the `QuerySet`. For example with:

```
from django.db.models import QuerySet

class MyModelQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def close(self):
        return self.update(status='closed', open_time=None, opener=None)

    def close_stuff(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get_stuff_to_close_query_set(*args, **kwargs).close()

    def get_stuff_to_close_query_set(self, time):
        self.filter(…)
```

Then we can plug this into the `MyModel`:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # …
    objects = MyModelQuerySet.as_manager()
```